# In EMACS on windows how to keep some files fixed in Recent File List?

Tags: emacs, gnu, recent-file-list

In GNU EMACS 24.3, I use recentf to show the recently opened files. I would like to keep certain makefiles so that I do not have to type the whole path whenever I want to switch projects.

Is it possible to make certain files sticky or persistent in the list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly answering your question, but I think it would serve the same purpose. I bookmark the files I'm using most often.

You can read more about it here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookMarks

but in a nutshell: <kbd>C-x r m</kbd> bookmarks the currently open file (works on `dired` buffers too). <kbd>C-x r b</kbd> loads the bookmarked file with word completion.

Answer (score 1):

Set the length of the recent files list to a high number. For example:

```
(setq recentf-max-saved-items 1000)
```

This way the makefiles won't drop out from the list if you visit them regularly. Also it is useful to keep a long recentf list and use a package which allows you to open files from it with completion. Here you can find some ways to do that: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-es/RecentFiles